# Program type already present androidx.exifinterface.R

Tags: android, gradle

I recently added `implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.6.4'` as a dependency in my android project and now Intellij is complaining that `Program type already present: androidx.exifinterface.R`. What does this mean and how do I fix this?

Note: this is meant to be a Q&A question. I've already found a solution and I want to share with others.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into an issue where android studio would complain that `Program type already present: androidx.exifinterface.R`. This happened after adding the `implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.6.4'` dependency. I had stumbled on this before with `androidx.asynclayoutinflater.R`. I've found the that adding something like the following to your module level gradle file will fix it:

```
configurations.all {
    // This is from a previous, similar issue
    exclude group: "androidx.asynclayoutinflater", module: "asynclayoutinflater"

    // This is the LOC that fixed the issue in this post
    exclude group: "androidx.exifinterface", module: "exifinterface"
}
```

The pattern seems to be:

```
if there's a complaint about androidx.MODULE_X.R already being present
then add 
    exclude group: "androidx.MODULE_X", module: "MODULE_X"
to configurations.all in module level gradle file
```

This worked for both asynclayoutinflater and now exifinterface. I don't know if the pattern scales but so far it has worked. My understanding of the underlying issue is that two dependencies in the module dependency graph (eg `com.google.android.play:core`) explicitly include the problematic module (eg `exifinterface`) and so we need to exlude one of those explicit dependencies. My understanding might be wrong.